# How can I display element with position absolut in Dialog window (material-ui) correctly?

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

I use React, TypeScript, StyledComponent and MaterialUI in my project.

I want to add button to Dialog window (material-ui) like this
[example img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nRB4B.png)

But if I add `position: absolut` to button I get a button with cropped piece.
[result img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LgpKL.png)

I tried to add `z-index` to this button, but it doesn't help to achieve the desired result.

How can I add button correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can remove the overflow-y from the dialog paper, just add the property PaperProps to your dialog.

```
<Dialog
  PaperProps={{
    style: { overflowY: "inherit" }
  }}
  onClose={handleClose}
  open={open}
>
```

Here a working example (in JS):

https://codesandbox.io/s/custom-close-button-on-dialogtitle-y5nln

You can find more about the Dialog API [here](https://material-ui.com/api/dialog/)